# candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'Record [10]' to 'Record' for 1st argument void getData(Record listofRecords, int & listSize);

Tags: c++

I don't understand this error. Can you please help? I am trying to take in a list, fill it with data, and use list size to the number of elements filled

The error I am getting is:

> main.cpp:26:6: note: candidate function not viable: no known
> conversion from 'Record [10]' to 'Record' for 1st argument
> void getData(Record listofRecords, int & listSize);

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
    

//Global variable
const int MAX_RECORDS = 10;

//Struct to organize the records
struct Record {
    string itemId;
    string itemName;
    int quantity;
    double price;
};

//function prototypes
void getData(Record listofRecords, int & listSize);



int main() {

    Record listOfRecords[MAX_RECORDS];
    int listSize;

    getData(listOfRecords,listSize);


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is self-explanatory. The function wants a single `Record` instance, but you are trying to give it an array of 10 `Record` instances.

I *suspect* you want `getData()` to take in the whole array, fill it in with data, and then set `listSize` to the number of elements actually filled, is that right? If so, then the `listofRecords` parameter would need to be declared as either:

```cpp
Record *listofRecords
```

or

```cpp
Record (&listofRecords)[10]
```